# Does the paladin's Divine Health feature protect against both common and magical diseases?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, paladin, disease

By 3rd level, a Paladin gains the following ability (PHB, pg. 85):

> **Divine Health**: The divine magic flowing through you makes you immune to disease.

Does this protect against both common AND magical disease?

There is no differentiation between the two. Disease is simply disease in the relevant entries (which I can't find anymore). A few spells afflict you with disease; sickly common folk may be diseased, and certain magical aura's on enemies may inflict a diseased state. Since these all count under the 'Disease' umbrella, and the Paladin trait simply says a magical energy is making you immune to disease... I assume this is read as "Immune to [all] disease."

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As you say: the game makes no such distinction between mundane and magical diseases with this ability, with all diseases just being *diseases* as far as it's concerned. **Divine Health** will protect you from both the measles and death dog saliva, equally.

This is congruent with how Paladins' miraculous healthiness works in many prior editions of the game too, so it's certainly not an oversight to not distinguish between mundane and magical disease.

Aside, the game otherwise does make a distinction between magical and mundane diseases (see the descriptions of spells like *raise dead* and *resurrection*) but **Divine Health** doesn't discriminate and defeats them all.