# How can a disease be removed, if the description of the disease does not specify?

Tags: dnd-5e, healing, disease

The description of a Gas Spore's Death Burst [MM p. 138] says (in part):

> Spores invade an infected creature's system, killing the creature in a number of hours equal to 1d12 plus the creature's constitution score, unless the disease is removed.

It does not say how the disease may be removed.

The DMG is very vague on disease.  Regarding removal:

> A simple outbreak might amount to little more than a small drain on party resources, curable by casting of *lesser restoration*. A more complicated outbreak can form the basis of one or more adventures....

**What spells, abilities or tools can be used to remove disease where a specific cure is not mentioned in the disease's description?**

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate, because it focuses more on causes than cures: [What happened to disease in D&D 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48895)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Sadly the rules on curing disease do not seem to be organized in a single section of any of the rule books.** Here are all the options I can find:

## Spells

***Lesser Restoration*** (2nd level) can end 1 disease afflicting the target

***Raise Dead*** (5th level, 500gp consumed material component) cures non-magical diseases that afflicted the deceased at the time of its death.
Likewise ***Resurrection*** (7th level, 1000gp consumed material component).
***True Resurrection*** (9th level, 25,000gp consumed material component) removes all magical *and* non-magical diseases that afflicted the deceased at the time of its death.

***Heal*** (6th level) ends any diseases affecting the target (among other things)

***Hero's Feast*** (6th level, 1000gp consumed material component) cures all diseases in up to 12 creatures who consume it

***Mass Heal*** (9th level) cures all diseases in any creatures you can see (and choose to target) within the 60 foot range (arguably you may have to heal them at least one hp for this to work, limiting you to 700 creatures.)

## Magic Items

*To keep this list from getting too long, please only include items that specifically deal with disease, not ones that merely cast a spell that deals with disease.*

**Keoghtom's Ointment** is a multiple-use consumable that fixes diseases (among other things)

**Elixer of Health** is a consumable that fixes diseases (amongst other things)

**Periapt of Health** makes you immune to disease while worn, and suppresses any existing ones.

A Night Hag's **Heartstone** can cure any diseases, but might be hard to obtain.

**Potion of Vitality** cures any diseases, but that's really a side-note compared to its major effects.

## Other

The **Paladins' Lay on Hands** ability says it can cure 1 disease if they spend 5 hp of their pool.

The **Transmutation Wizards' Master Transmuter** ability allows them to remove all diseases (along with curses, poisons, hp damage) on a creature they touch with their transmuter's stone (consuming the stone).

## Downtime

Three days spent recuperating will allow you to make a CON save to gain advantage on saves against one disease (or poison).  (This obviously is only useful against diseases where there is some existing saving throw mechanism to become cured.)

Comment: Please comment if you can find any options I've missed. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, 10th lvl monks are immune to disease and poison.  3rd lvl paladins are immune to disease.  Leveling up to gain those class features could cure a disease?

Comment: Way of Mercy Monks can remove a disease with the use of their Hands of Healing feature at 6th level.

Answer (score 12):

Lesser restoration is stated as such in the Player's Handbook:

> Lesser Restoration
>   2nd-level abjuration
>   Casting Time: 1 action
>   Range: Touch
>   Components: V, S
>   Duration: Instantaneous
>   You touch a creature and can end either one disease or
>   one condition afflicting it. The condition can be blinded,
>   deafened, paralyzed, or poisoned.

It only lists the conditions specifically, because it is implied that any disease, *unless stated otherwise* can be cured with it.

Likewise, Paladins have a feature known as Lay on Hands that is stated as such:

> Alternatively, you can expend 5 hit points from your
>   pool o f healing to cure the target o f one disease or
>   neutralize one poison affecting it. You can cure multiple
>   diseases and neutralize multiple poisons with a single
>   use o f Lay on Hands, expending hit points separately
>   for each one.

Comment: Paladins also happen to be immune to it entirely :D
[Does the paladin's Divine Health feature protect against both common and magical diseases?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60292/does-the-paladins-divine-health-feature-protect-against-both-common-and-magical)

Comment: @Airatome I think monks too, at a certain level?